# Axis2C Savan - Publishing to Data Sink failed

Tags: c, web-services, axis2c, ws-eventing

all,
I am trying to get familiar with Axis2/C framework and I am not able to get working the sample(weather service - subscriber - listener) for WS-Eventing that comes with Savan module. According to the log file, there is a problem with url adress, but I donť understand, what might be the problem. Does anybody have the same problem?

```
[Thu Oct 24 21:25:57 2013] [debug] publisher.c(209) [savan] Publishing to:urn:uuid:4e482bf8-3cd3-1e31-3822-080027ac2daf
[Thu Oct 24 21:25:57 2013] [debug] publisher.c(280) [savan] Publishing to:http://localhost:9090/axis2/services/listener
[Thu Oct 24 21:25:57 2013] [error] publisher.c(290) Could not create the filter module
[Thu Oct 24 21:25:57 2013] [error] publisher.c(229) Publishing to the Data Sink:http://localhost:9090/axis2/services/listener proviced by subscriber:urn:uuid:4e482bf8-3cd3-1e31-3822-080027ac2daf Failed.
Check whether the Data Sink url is correct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In the example there is a bug. In the file **listener_skeleton.c** on the line 84 there must be changed the name of operation to be the same as the name in **services.xml**.

Original:

```
axutil_array_list_add(svc_skeleton->func_array, env, "weather");
```

Fixed:

```
axutil_array_list_add(svc_skeleton->func_array, env, "send");
```